# How to get the current absolute path of xquery using Marklogic APIs

Tags: marklogic

Say, I have a module abc.xqy in multiple directories:

- /Adir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy
- /Bdir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy
- /Cdir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy
- /Ddir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy

This is triggered/invoked from java I want to find the absolute location of the this file when it is executed (when the xqy is executed I want to get the path within that), based on which I can write logic. How it can be achieved?
`xdmp:get-invoked-path` is not working when I do a newmoduleinvoke from java. It works only when I do a `xdmp:invoke`.

Comment: In detail, Say, I have a file abc.xqy in side 
/Adir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy . 
/Bdir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy . 
/Cdir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy . 
/Ddir/dir1/dir2/abc.xqy . 

This is triggered/invoked from java 
I want to find the absolute location of the this file when it is executed (when the xqy is executed I want to get the path within that), based on which I can write logic. How it can be achieved?

xdmp:get-invoked-path is not working when I do a newmoduleinvoke from java. It works only when i do a xdmp:invoke.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to detect which physical file you are in exactly (particularly if it is a library module) without throwing and catching an exception, and analyzing the stack trace. But next to `xdmp:get-invoked-path`, you also have `xdmp:get-request-path`, and `xdmp:modules-root` might also be relevant..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Try [xdmp:get-request-url](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-url). From the documentation:

> Returns the portion of the URL following the host_name:port_number. The output does not include any fragment identifier supplied with the URL (that is, it does not include the # sign or anything following the # sign). Note that when a URL rewriter is used, this function returns the rewritten URL.

That should identify the main module being used. I don't see a way to identify a current library module.